# Number of Compute Units corresponding to the number of work groups

Tags: opencl, nvidia, simd

I need some clarification. I'm developing OpenCL on my laptop running a small nvidia GPU (310M). When I query the device for `CL_DEVICE_MAX_COMPUTE_UNITS`, the result is 2. I read the number of work groups for running a kernel should correspond to the number of compute units ([Heterogenous Computing with OpenCL](http://www.heterogeneouscompute.org/?page_id=7), Chapter 9, p. 186), otherwise it would waste too much global memory bandwitdh.

Also the chip is specified to have 16 cuda cores (which correspond to PEs I believe). Does that mean theoretically, the most performant setup for this gpu, regarding global memory bandwith, is to have two work groups with 16 work items each?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

While setting the number of work groups to be equal to `CL_DEVICE_MAX_COMPUTE_UNITS` might be sound advice on some hardware, it certainly *is not* on NVIDIA GPUs.

On the CUDA architecture, an OpenCL compute unit is the equivalent of a multiprocessor (which can have either 8, 32 or 48 cores at the time of writing), and these are designed to be able to simultaneously run up to 8 work groups (blocks in CUDA) *each*. At larger input data sizes, you might choose to run thousands of work groups, and your particular GPU can handle up to 65535 x 65535 work groups per kernel launch.

OpenCL has another device attribute `CL_KERNEL_PREFERRED_WORK_GROUP_SIZE_MULTIPLE`. If you query that on an NVIDIA device, it will return 32 (this is the "warp", or natural SIMD width of the hardware). That value is the work group size multiple you should use; work group sizes can be up to 512 items each, depending on the resources consumed by each work item. The standard rule of thumb for your particular GPU is that you require at least 192 active work items per compute unit (threads per multiprocessor in CUDA terms) to cover all the latency the architecture and potentially obtain either full memory bandwidth or full arithmetic throughput, depending on the nature of your code.

NVIDIA ship a good document called "OpenCL Programming Guide for the CUDA Architecture" in the CUDA toolkit. You should take some time to read it, because it contains all the specifics of how the NVIDIA OpenCL implementation maps onto the features of their hardware, and it will answer the questions you have raised here.

Answer (score 2):

I don't even think matching your workgroup count to compute units is a good idea on a CPU.  It is better to oversubscribe the cores by several fold.  This allows the workload to move around dynamically (in workgroup quanta) as various processors come on line or get distracted with other work.  Workgroup `count = CL_DEVICE_MAX_COMPUTE_UNITS` only really works well on a machine that is doing absolutely nothing else and wasting lots of energy keeping unused cores awake.