# What is the relationship between NVIDIA GPUs' CUDA cores and OpenCL computing units?

Tags: cuda, parallel-processing, opencl

My computer has a GeForce GTX 960M which is claimed by NVIDIA to have 640 CUDA cores. However, when I run clGetDeviceInfo to find out the number of computing units in my computer, it prints out 5 (see the figure below). It sounds like CUDA cores are somewhat different from what OpenCL considers as computing units? Or maybe a group of CUDA cores form an OpenCL computing unit? Can you explain this to me?

[image]

Comment: There's a table that maps OpenCL <-> CUDA linguo floating around the internet. What OpenCL calls a Compute Unit is CUDA's Streaming Multiprocessor. CUDA "cores" are essentially ALUs/FPUs. GTX 960M has 5 SMs with 128 cores each, that's 640 in total.

Comment: @Angy Lettuce Thanks for the answer. So, if I understand this correctly, every work-group will be executed in a computing unit; therefore, given max work-group size 1024 the best parallelism that I can do in this GPU is to execute 1024*5=5120 work-items at the same. Is this right?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> What is the relationship between NVIDIA GPUs' CUDA cores and OpenCL computing units?

Your GTX 960M is a Maxwell device with 5 Streaming Multiprocessors, each with 128 CUDA cores, for a total of [640 CUDA cores](http://www.geforce.com/hardware/notebook-gpus/geforce-gtx-960m/specifications).

The NVIDIA Streaming Multiprocessor [is equivalent to an OpenCL Compute Unit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9326430/number-of-compute-units-corresponding-to-the-number-of-work-groups).  The previously linked answer will also give you some useful information that may help with your kernel sizing question in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

> The CUDA architecture is a close match to the OpenCL architecture.
>
> A CUDA device is built around a scalable array of multithreaded Streaming Multiprocessors (SMs). A multiprocessor corresponds to an OpenCL compute unit.
>
> A multiprocessor executes a CUDA thread for each OpenCL work-item and a thread block for each OpenCL work-group. A kernel is executed over an OpenCLNDRange by a grid of thread blocks. As illustrated in Figure 2-1, each of the thread blocks that execute a kernel is therefore uniquely identified by its work-group ID, and each thread by its global ID or by a combination of its local ID and work-group ID.

Copied from OpenCL Programming Guide for the CUDA Architecture http://www.nvidia.com/content/cudazone/download/OpenCL/NVIDIA_OpenCL_ProgrammingGuide.pdf