# OpenCL: Confused by CL_DEVICE_MAX_COMPUTE_UNITS

Tags: opencl

I'm confused by this CL_DEVICE_MAX_COMPUTE_UNITS. For instance my Intel GPU on Mac, this number is 48. Does this mean the max number of parallel tasks run at the same time is 48 or the multiple of 48, maybe 96, 144...? (I know each compute unit is composed of 1 or more processing elements and each processing element is actually in charge of a "thread". What if these each of the 48 compute units is composed of more than 1 processing elements ). In other words, for my Mac, the "ideal" speedup, although impossible in reality, is 48 times faster than a CPU core (we assume the single "core" computation speed of CPU and GPU is the same), or the multiple of 48, maybe 96, 144...?

Comment: It's complicated. The term "compute unit" is not strictly defined. Maybe someone can give a "good" answer nevertheless, but I'd like to give a pointer to one related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9326430/number-of-compute-units-corresponding-to-the-number-of-work-groups (there are several other related ones - not sure if one of them is even a duplicate of this)

Answer (score 4):

Summary: Your speedup is a little complicated, but your machine's (Intel GPU, probably GEN8 or GEN9) fp32 throughput **768** FLOPs per (GPU) clock and 1536 for fp16.  Let's assume fp32, so something less than 768x (maybe a third of this depending on CPU speed).  See below for the reasoning and some very important caveats.

*A Quick Aside on CL_DEVICE_MAX_COMPUTE_UNITS:*
Intel does something wonky when with CL_DEVICE_MAX_COMPUTE_UNITS with its GPU driver.

From the [clGetDeviceInfo](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenCL/sdk/2.0/docs/man/xhtml/clGetDeviceInfo.html) (OpenCL 2.0).  CL_DEVICE_MAX_COMPUTE_UNITS says

> The number of parallel compute units on the OpenCL device. A
>   work-group executes on a single compute unit. The minimum value is 1.

However, the Intel Graphics driver does not actually follow this definition and instead returns the number of EUs (Execution Units) --- An EU a grouping of the SIMD ALUs and slots for 7 different SIMD threads (registers and what not).  Each SIMD thread represents 8, 16, or 32 workitems depending on what the compiler picks (we want higher, but register pressure can force us lower).

A workgroup is actually limited to a "Slice" [(see the figure in section 5.5 "Slice Architecture"](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-graphics-developers-guides)), which happens to be 24 EUs (in recent HW). Pick the GEN8 or GEN9 documents. Each slice has it's own SLM, barriers, and L3.  Given that your apple book is reporting 48 EUs, I'd say that you have two slices.

Maximum Speedup:
Let's ignore this major annoyance and work with the EU number (and from those arch docs above). For "speedup" I'm comparing a single threaded FP32 calculation on the CPU.  With good parallelization etc on the CPU, the speedup would be less, of course.

Each of the 48 EUs can issue two SIMD4 operations per clock in ideal circumstances.  Assuming those are fused multiply-add's (so really two ops), that gives us:

```
48 EUs * 2 SIMD4 ops per EU * 2 (if the op is a fused multiply add) 
= 192 SIMD4 ops per clock
= 768 FLOPs per clock for single precision floating point
```

So your ideal speedup is actually **~768**.  But there's a bunch of things that chip into this ideal number.

1. Setup and teardown time.  Let's ignore this (assume the WL time dominates the runtime).
2. The GPU clock maxes out around a gigahertz while the CPU runs faster.  Factor that ratio in. (crudely 1/3 maybe? 3Ghz on the CPU vs 1Ghz on the GPU).
3. If the computation is not heavily multiply-adds "mads", divide by 2 since I doubled above. Many important workloads are "mad"-dominated though.
4. The execution is mostly non-divergent.  If a SIMD thread branches into an if-then-else, the entire SIMD thread (8,16,or 32 workitems) has to execute that code.
5. Register banking collisions delays can reduce EU ALU throughput.  Typically the compiler does a great job avoiding this, but it can theoretically chew into your performance a bit (usually a few percent depending on register pressure).
6. Buffer address calculation can chew off a few percent too (EU must spend time doing integer compute to read and write addresses).
7. If one uses too much SLM or barriers, the GPU must leave some of the EU's idle so that there's enough SLM for each work item on the machine.  (You can tweak your algorithm to fix this.)
8. We must keep the WL compute bound.  If we blow out any cache in the data access hierarchy, we run into scenarios where no thread is ready to run on an EU and must stall.  Assume we avoid this.
   ?. I'm probably forgetting other things that can go wrong.

We call the *efficiency* the percentage of theoretical perfect.  So if our workload runs at ~530 FLOPs per clock, then we are 60% efficient of the theoretical 768.  I've seen very carefully tuned workloads exceed 90% efficiency, but it definitely can take some work.

Answer (score 1):

The ideal speedup you can get is the total number of processing elements which in your case corresponds to 48 * number of processing elements per compute unit. I do not know of a way to get the number of processing elements from OpenCL (that does not mean that it is not possible), however you can just google it for your GPU.

Up to my knowledge, a compute unit consists of one or multiple processing elements (for GPUs usually a lot), a register file, and some local memory. The threads of a compute unit are executed in a SIMD (single instruction multiple data) fashion. This means that the threads of a compute unit all execute the same operation but on different data.

Also, the speedup you get depends on how you execute a kernel function. Since a single work-group can not run on multiple compute units you need a sufficient number of work-groups in order to fully utilize all of the compute units. In addition, the work-group size should be a multiple of CL_KERNEL_PREFERRED_WORK_GROUP_SIZE_MULTIPLE.